# SAP PI message mapping does not map values

Tags: mapping, sap-pi, sap-xi

In SAP PI 7.4 I'm experiencing some difficulties in trying to map something in a message mapping which would seem quite straightforward.

Input is something like this.

```
<Employee>
      <ExternalIdList>
          <ExternalId>aaa</ExternalId>
          <ExternalId>bbb</ExternalId>
          <ExternalId>ccc</ExternalId>
      </ExternalIdList>
</Employee>
```

I need this to map to something of the following structure:

```
<Newobject>
 <ExternalEmployeeList>
  <ExternalEmployee>
   <ExternalId>aaa</ExternalId>
  </ExternalEmployee>
  <ExternalEmployee>
   <ExternalId>bbb</ExternalId>
  </ExternalEmployee>
  <ExternalEmployee>
   <ExternalId>ccc</ExternalId>
  </ExternalEmployee>
 </ExternalEmployeeList>
</Newobject>
```

When trying to map, I'd do this as follows:

- `Employee` -> `NewObject`
- `ExternalIdList` -> `ExternalEmployeeList`
- `ExternalId` -> `ExternalEmployee`
- `ExternalId` -> `ExternalId`

When testing the mapping, 3 `ExternalEmployee` nodes are made, but only the first contains the value 'aaa' in the `ExternalId`.  The other 2 `ExternalEmployee` nodes don't get an `ExternalId`:

```
<Newobject>
 <ExternalEmployeeList>
  <ExternalEmployee>
   <ExternalId>aaa</ExternalId>
  </ExternalEmployee>
  <ExternalEmployee/>
  <ExternalEmployee/>
  </ExternalEmployee>
 </ExternalEmployeeList>
</Newobject>
```

I've already tried quite some node functions or changed the context, but nothing seems to be working.  What is the recommended solution for this?

Maybe add a XSLT mapping beforehand to insert a level between the `ExternalIdList` and the `ExternalId` in the input message?  It seems like a lot of fuzz for this.

Thanks in advance, every tip in the right direction is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem should be a missing context change in tag ExternalId.

try to fix the mapping in the following way:

ExternalEmployee (target) = ExternalEmployee

ExternalId (target) = **splitByValue(ExternalId)**

configure splitByValue choosing "**Each Value**" option

[image: ExternalIDScreenshot]

**Also be sure that target ExternalEmployee have 1..unbounded occurrence !**

This is the result
[image: Result]

Best regards!